# How to extract resources files from .dat file?

Tags: c, extract

I already have the extractor source about the .dat file.
but this source is used in other games.

However, the two games were made in the same company and maintain a similar format.

so I want to get help.

```
// Sample Code.....
#define WIN32_LEARN_AND_MEAN

#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <direct.h>


struct dat
{ // total 25byte
    unsigned long offset; // 4byte
    char name[13]; // 13byte
    unsigned long size; // 4byte;
    char *data; // 4byte;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int value;
    char input[512];
    printf(" * Select mode\n  1: Pack\n  2: Unpack\n Choose: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    if(value == 1)
    {
        printf("\n\n *Mode: Pack\n  Datname: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
        dat_pack(input);
    }
    else if(value == 2)
    {
        printf("\n\n *Mode: Unpack\n  Datname: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
        dat_unpack(input);
    }
    printf("\nPress any key to continue\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    getch();
    return 0;
}


int dat_unpack(char *file_name)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");

    if (fp == 0)
    {
        printf(" File does not exist: %s\n", file_name);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        long i;
        long len;
        long total;
        struct dat *dat;
        fread(&total, 4, 1, fp);
        len = sizeof(struct dat);
        dat = malloc(len*total);
        memset(dat, 0, len*total);
        *strstr(file_name, ".") = 0; // cute trick :p

        printf("\n reading Infomation... ");

        for (i = 0; i<total; i++)
        {
            fread(&(dat[i]), 17, 1, fp);
            if (i > 0) dat[i - 1].size = dat[i].offset - dat[i - 1].offset;
        }

        printf("ok.\n Total %d data(s) in dat file.\n", --total);

        for (i = 0; i<total; i++)
        {
            file_write(&(dat[i]), fp, file_name);
        }

        printf(" Unpack Complete!\n");

        free(dat);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

and this source can unpack the next things.

[mon.dat is working upper source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xykes.png)
so, then,

now I want to extract something from a '.dat file'
that looks something like this:

[cthugha.dat - it was not working from upper extract sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CD0m.png)
:(

Please let me know what I need to do in order to extract the components of the cthugha.dat file I listed below.

Comment: That is not related to neither C++, unpack nor the dat-protocol. Without specification of the file format in question it will be a matter of trial, error & luck. It doesn't really help that `cthugha.dat` is "similar" to `mom.dat` if the code is specifically written for the format of `mom.dat`. Screenshots of hexdumps don't help either.

Comment: Note:  compilers are allowed to insert padding bytes between members.  If you don't want the padding bytes, search your compiler's documentation for any `pragma` for *packing* a structure.

Comment: I'm chilling in my old age and no longer care so much if folks are compiling C code with a C++ compiler unless it really does matter--which does not seem to be the case here--but do read the tag info to make sure the tag fits before using the tag. IF the tag has no info, it is probably poorly defined and shouldn't be used unless you're really, really sure it doesn't mean something else.

Comment: IMHO, you are better off declaring a C++ class with data members (like using `std::string`) and using *serialization* techniques to read the data members from the model; don't try to model a structure exactly to the file format.

Comment: You really ought to *define* "a '.dat file' ". The file name/extension means *nothing*.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged as C++, you could model a *record* with a class, then write some methods to read the class (object) from a binary stream:

```
class Record
{
  public:
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long offset; 
    std::string   name;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;

  void load_from_file(std::istream& input);
};

void Record::load_from_file(std::istream& input)
{
  // Use uint8_t as a byte.
  offset = 0UL;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    uint8_t byte;
    input.read((unsigned char *) &byte, 1);
    // Assume Big Endian
    offset = offset * 256 + byte;
  }
  // read in other fields from file.
  //...
}
```

Modeling the class to the data file record allows the program to take advantage of safer data structures.

The input method allows conversion from the data file format to the platform format.  For example, the input file would allow you to read the multibyte integers into the platform's format, regardless of the platform's endianness.

The `std::vector` allows containing data without knowing the quantity of data at runtime.

Example usage:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (true)
{
  r.load_from_file(data_file);
  if (data_file)
  {
    database.push_back(r);
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
}
```